# Query from many tables

Tags: sql-server

I have tables like this:

```
1-Subjects:
----------------------------------
SubjectID  PK
SubjectName
```

...

```
2- Courses:
----------------------------------
CourseID   PK
SubjectID  FK
CourseName
Year
Semester
```

...

```
3- Students:
----------------------------------
StudentID    PK
FirstName
LastName
```

....

```
4-StudentScores:
----------------------------------
ScoreID     PK
CourseID    FK
StudentID   FK
TotalScore
```

....

Now I want to query tables By **Year** and **Semester**, like this:

```
StudentID  |  FirstName  | LastName  | SubjectName | TotalScore
```

This Query is for a specified Semester; for Example: Year-2017   Semester-2

Please Help Me!

Comment: Homework question spotted :) . What did you try ?

Comment: Your last edit shows only the schema. Prabhat wants to see what SQL statements you have tried so far. Show the input data and what you want the report to look like. The report headings aren't good enough to make the problem clear enough.

Comment: This site is not homework site. You try something and don't get what you want, then ask us with CODE which you have tried.

Comment: As your given requirement are not enough to get your exact expected result,Add some sample data to get your expected result

Comment: It is not a homework! I tried very very...

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may helps you

```
SELECT   s.StudentID
        ,s.FirstName
        ,s.LastName
        ,s.SubjectName
        ,s.TotalScore
FROM Students
INNER JOIN StudentScores c 
    ON c.StudentID = s.StudentID
INNER JOIN Courses cr 
    ON cr.CourseID = c.CourseID
WHERE DATEPART(Yr, [cr.Year]) = 2017
    AND  DATEPART(QUARTER,[cr.Semester]) = 2
```

Comment: SubjectName is in Subjects Table; Not in Students Table